# Auto increasing number in img src

Tags: php

Suppose I have 100 images, named 1.png,2.png,3.png...so on.

Is there any coding that it automatically increases the number.

For Eg,
I have

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details;?>6.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images;?>6.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

so now it should automatically do

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details;?>7.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images;?>7.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details;?>8.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images;?>8.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and so on..

Auto increase number..

Comment: *Auto increase number* - on what action?

Comment: Is this information stored in a DB?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If I just wrote once <img src="1.png">, then it should automatically go one number up have the image

Comment: @chris85 No, it is not in db.

Comment: Are the images in their own directory? Perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: yes.. web.com/images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop for that.

Example:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++): ?>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: I think. According to your answer. `src="<?php echo $images;?>6.png"` should be `src="<?php echo $images.$i;?>.png"`

Comment: your code won't work, please reread before you post your aswer

Comment: Can you also help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012150/skipping-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

you could set it in the url parameters:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <?php $n = (isset($_GET['n'])) ? $_GET['n'] : 0; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $details;?>?n=<?php echo $n+1 ?>.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images . $n;?>.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Guess i completely misunderstood the question
I thought it had to increment every time the link was clicked

so for an alternative answer then the other 2

```
<?php foreach(range(1, 100) as $n): ?>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details . $n;?>.php" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="<?php echo $images . $n;?>.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```