# Skipping For Loop

Tags: php

After having a solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002338/auto-increasing-number-in-img-src) question.

my code:-

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++):?>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
      <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

So now assume that there is now image as **8.png**, so `for loop` should skip that and go to next, without showing no image.

[Result is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyfSw.png)
And I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUGNW.png)

The red Portion should not be displayed.

Comment: you need to check whether that image is avilable or not.

Comment: yes sometimes there may not be images.., its an example there are 100 images

Comment: What is inside `$image`? How do you define that? Where is the actual image stored?

Comment: `$image' is nothing but the path for images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Comment: But where is it stored? On your server? If so, what's the path to the folder?

Comment: http://localhost/downloads/vf/images/ is the path and it is known as $images

Comment: @bhansa try to sort out two questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists is totally different from mine.

Comment: @ChiragJain Please be specific with your problem, below answers already solves your problem. Did you try any of them instead of editing the question?

Comment: @bhansa Yes, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012221/7678788 with the answer but it doesn't display any images..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012150/skipping-for-loop#comment78984781_46012150) that the URL to the images is `localhost/downloads/vf/images`, I will assume that with usage of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` takes care of the folders outside public (which could be something like `C:\users\chirag\htdocs\`, but that `$_SERVER` variable should take care of that. If that's not the case, find the full path and use that instead - as `file_exists()` requires the system path, not the public path/URL. This also assumes that you use a relative path for the `$images` variable, which means that you have `$images = "/downloads/vf/images/";` and not `$images = "localhost/downloads/vf/images/";`.

With that assumption, we can now use `file_exists()` - because that takes the system path, not the URL.

```
<?php 
$images = "/downloads/vf/images/";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++):
    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i.".png"))
        continue; // Skip this iteration if it can't find the file 
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
          <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

- [PHP.net on `continue;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)
- [PHP.net on `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [PHP.net on `file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: `$images` should just be the relative path, so it should be `/downloads/vf/images/` and not the full path (`localhost/downloads/vf/images`).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a check condition if the image exists or not, there are certain methods like [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++): 
    if(file_exists("file_path")){ ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
<? { php endfor; ?>
```

This might help you: [How to check if image exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

File_exists is function check for the file exists or not

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++): 
   if (file_exists($images.$i.'.png')) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">

<?php } endfor; ?>
```

check this like for more detail

[PHP: How to check if image file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Comment: you can't use [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) with a url, only a local filepath

Comment: please answer me with my coding only; http://www.example.com/images/ is equal to $images

Comment: what about .png?

Comment: :) . check out.

Comment: Sorry its not working. i have edited my codes in question, plz help it with the newest!

Comment: @ChiraqJain Please explain _what_ isn't working. And by changing your question after it has received answers you risk invalidating the answers and thus the time people spent on your question. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I used  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++):
 if (file_exists($images.$i.'.png')) { ?>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
      <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } endfor; ?>

Comment: @ModusTollens question is not totally changed, I just added the full description. You may see the edits.

Comment: @ChiraqJain Ok, but please take care it doesn't turn into a [Chameleon Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @ChiragJain, people are not here to provide a piece of code that works, we are here to provide an idea how to solve the problem, and in that case you have to try.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `continue` directive. I also suggest you drop the use of `:` and `endfor` and all the extra PHP start/end blocks for readability and performance reasons.

```
<?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    if (!is_readable($images . $i . '.png'))
      continue;

    echo "<img src=\"${images}${i}.png\" alt=\"$i\">";
  }
?>
```

Comment: it is not necessary that always there will no 8.png. it may also be that it doesn't have 4.png..

Comment: I have div also with them... Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002338/auto-increasing-number-in-img-src before editing it!

Comment: `is_readable` checks for the file on disk... this will skip any file that is missing provided the path presented to `is_readable` is correct.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the keyword `continue` inside any loop, the rest of the iteration after that would be skipped.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++): ?>

      <?php if ($i == 8) continue;>

      <img src="<?php echo $images . $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
<?php endfor; ?>
```

This keyword is common for a lot of languages.

Also in PHP, the `continue` accepts a numeric argument which tells it how many iterations it should skip.

[PHP continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: It's not my downvote, but OP said in a comment above that it might not necessarily be 8.png that's missing, it might be 4.png - but again, not my downvote. Oh, and it appears that you have a slight syntax error